# How to add element and attribute to xml file in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I want to get name and email from form and write to xml file exists on the server.I have searched on the internet but I can't do that. Anyone who can give me the code.

xml format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Infos>
<Info name="name" email="email" />
</Infos>
```

The code is better if it is generalized. My code:

```
 <html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function addData(fileName, targetName, elementName, attribute, value)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: filename,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                $("<"+elementName+" "+attribute+"="+value+"/>").appendTo($(xml).find(targetName));
            }
        }); 
     }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can only write to file on a server. Question is too broad...you need to be a lot more specific